# Join 2n points in pairs on the circumference of a circle using n non-intersecting chords

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Show that if 2n points are marked on the circumference of a circle and if a<sub>n</sub> is the number of ways of joining them in pairs by n non-intersecting chords then a<sub>n</sub> = C<sub>n</sub>.

-Not sure how to approach this problem; the chapter this is from is on recurrence, although I'm not sure how to apply what I've learned in this chapter to this particular question. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does $C_n$ stand for here? Is it the Catalan number?

Comment: Show it using recurrence formula and induction. For $n=0, 1$ it is obvious. So fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and assume, that $a_{2k} = C_k$ for every $k<n$. Using that assumption try to proof, that also $a_{2n} = C_n$.

Comment: Do you know that the Catalan numbers satisfy the recurrence $C_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^nC_kC_{n-k}$? That’s the tool that you need here.

Comment: The base case is clear to me, but for the induction step itself how would I use this assumption and manipulate the equation to show that they're equal?

Comment: And I didn't know that recurrence, does this mean the proof would be as simple as a reference to this recurrence, basically saying that since the base case is confirmed and the assumption above, by this Catalan recurrence it follows that $a_n = C_n$ much like the way Fibonacci sequence related questions can be proven? Or am I over simplifying this?